# What should be the correct way to assign a value to a non-empty void* pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, compiler-warnings, void-pointers

I've the following code:

```
void funcA(void*   pArg)
{
    STRUCTA abc;
    .
    . // Some processing here
    .

    if (pArg)
       (STRUCTA *)pArg = abc;
}
```

the problem is, this code is throwing up the following warning:
warning: target of assignment not really an lvalue; this will be a hard error in the future

Without the cast, I'll get another warning that I'm trying to dereference a void pointer...

As warnings are being treated as errors, I can't use this code - But I really can't use any other pointer type than void* as the argument. Is there an elegant solution I'm missing?

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning a `STRUCTA` to a pointer to `STRUCTA`.

Rather do:

```
*((STRUCTA *)pArg) = abc;
```

Answer (score 5):

`(STRUCTA *)pArg` is of pointer type, while `abc` isn't. You need to dereference the pointer:

```
*(STRUCTA *)pArg = abc;
```

Comment: Thanks for the succinct reply...but Benoit had answered 2 mins earlier with the exact same explanation, so had to mark him as the right answer !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
memcpy(pArg, &abc, sizeof(abc));
```

However you must make sure that pArg points to sizeof(abc) bytes of allocated memory.

Comment: The accepted answer is much more elegant, and points out the mistake I'd been making...

Comment: Still, memcpy is probably the way to go here. Anything that does *(..) = .. is not elegant in my eyes.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe `pArg = (void *) abc;` ?

EDIT:

`pArg = (void *) (&abc);` ?

Comment: @Marcelo - you are absolutely right. I missed the fact that abc was not a pointer to begin with.